# PHP Как загружать большие видео-файлы?

Tags: php

Стоит apache2. Код написан php5.6, как лучше всего загружать видео чтобы не было ошибки 413 или Connection timeout? В дальнейшем планирую обрабатывать видео с помощью ffmpeg, после загрузки видео

```
$permitted_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$uploaddir = '/var/www/hosting/videos/';
$video = 'video-'.substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 16).basename($_FILES['video']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$video;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
//
} else {
    exit("Ошибка загрузки!\n");
}
$url = 'videos/'.$video;
```

Comment: Ну от ошибки 413 очевидно увеличивать лимиты на максимальный размер файла, а timeout непонятно откуда должен взяться тут

Comment: @andreymal ну почему непонятно откуда, банально человек не успевает загрузить файл за Х секунд/минут. Либо настройки Apache, который рвет соединение.

Comment: @zerxa если загрузка идёт и не зависла, то никакого таймаута не будет и загружать можно бесконечно долго

Comment: Хотя, может, кто-нибудь захочет прибить слишком долго работающий php-скрипт... тут я сходу не знаю, отсчёт длительности работы скрипта начинается до или после загрузки файла

Answer (score 0):

Эти ошибки вполне ожидаемы при загрузке больших файлов. Вам лучше всего использовать актуальную версию `PHP` и использовать Ajax для загрузки (хоть это и не решит вашу проблему).

Первая ваша проблема - это таймаут, вы не успеваете загрузить данные на ваш сервер за указанное время, вы можете убрать таймат на стороне Apache и PHP.
Откройте файл `httpd.conf` и измените следующий параметр:

```
# было
# LimitRequestBody 1
# стало
LimitRequestBody 0
```

В файле `php.ini` найдите `max_execution_time` и измените на:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

Этого должно хватить, но вы можете установить и большее значение.

В файле `php.ini` измените данные для максимального размера загружаемого файла:

```
# максимальный размер загружаемого файла будет 1,000 МБ
post_max_size = 1000M 
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

Вообще, по хорошему для загрузки больших файлов вы должны создать отдельный проект на другом порте и именно через него загружать большие файлы, так как подобные настройки могут негативно сказаться на вашем основном проекте.

Comment: Спасибо, но чёт я не могу найти в apache2.conf LimitRequestBody

Comment: А как можно использовать ajax для загрузки видео? Не приведёте пример?

Comment: PHP и apacche2 перезапустил и поправил но 413 Request Entity Too Large / cloudflare никуда не исчезла

Comment: @zavsc ээ, cloudflare? Ну на его бесплатном тарифе лимит 100МБ и вы ничего с этим не сделаете

Comment: Хорошо спасибо, ну так что делать с апачем?